# When does $ \operatorname{im} f= \ker f \neq \vec{o_V}$ or $\operatorname{im} f=\ker g\neq \vec{o_W}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\renewcommand{\img}{\operatorname{im}}$
Considering an endomorphism $f: V\rightarrow V$ when does $\img f= \ker f \neq \vec{o_V}$?

The only case that I can think of is when $f$ is both injective ($\ker f=\vec{o_V}$) and nilpotent (which implies that $\img f\subset \ker f$).

But in that case of course $\img f= \ker f=\vec{o_V}$

What I wonder is: are there cases in which happens that $\img f= \ker f \neq \vec{o_V}$ ?

(I'm not looking for just an example but possibly for something more general).

Supposing the same problem for two linear functions $f: V \rightarrow W$ and $g:W\rightarrow Z$

I'm looking for cases in which $\img f= \ker g\neq \vec{o_W}$.

I can only think of $g$ injective ($\ker g=\vec{o_W}$) and $f$ the null linear function.

In that case $\img f=\vec{o_W}= \ker g$ but again  I would like to know if there is a case in which is not equal to the zero vector.

I was also thinking about imposing that $g$ is injective ($\ker g=\vec{o_W}$) and that $g\circ f$ is the null function (which implies that $\img f\subset \ker g$) but firstly I don't know if this case is possible and then it would give me again $\img f= \ker g=\vec{o_W}$.

Could anyone help me with these problems? (Possibly suggesting general cases rather than particular examples)

Thanks a lot in advice

Answer (score 1):

Take your favorite vector space $V$ and your favorite automorphism $f:V \to V$. Then $$g:V\oplus V \to V \oplus V:(x+y)\mapsto (0+f(x))$$ satisfies $Ker(g)=0\oplus V=Im(g)$.

Now, suppose you have $f:V \to V$ such that $Ker(f)=Im(f)$, then $\bar{f}:V/Im(f)\to  Im(f)$ is an isomorphism. Thus $V \cong Im(f)\oplus Im(f)$ and $f$ is obtained using the above construction on $\bar{f}$.

Therefore, the construction in the first paragraph is essentially the only case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Sorry but in the first part of he answer you say that $kerg=0$ but therefore $f$ must be the null function to have $imf=kerg$, or not? And could you explain a little deeper what you said in the last part?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f:V\to V$ satisfying with $dim V<\infty$, then $dimV=2k$ because theorem of dimension. 
Let $B=\{v_1,...v_k,...,v_{2k}\}$ a base. Define $f(v_i)=0$ for $i=1,...,k$ and permutate the rest with $f(v_i)=v_j$ for $i=k+1,...,2k$, $j=1,...,k$

Comment: So in $\Bbb R^2$, are you asserting that $(x, y) \mapsto (0, y)$ works?

Comment: Hmm. If you see ker and im in R yes, but in R^2, (x,0)\neq(0,x)

Comment: @pjs36 Reading carefully the indices, I think what you'd get in $\mathbb R^2$ would be the map $[(x,y)\mapsto (y,0)]$.